# How do I change my storyboard width and objects from compact to any in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am trying to quickly convert the width of my Main.storyboard file from compact to any without having to duplicate my labels, buttons etc. I have tried several things in the source code of the file, but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: in your story board you have option to select view type like compact regular  oe any any and regular regular

Comment: Yes, but how do I change that and have my objects such as labels adapt. When I change it, everything disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your storyboard and at bottom you will see wAny hAny click on it and then just click on second row and second column as you can refer  from screenshots.
[image: screenshots]

And if you want that it should adjust according to screen width then add autolayout constraints on each elements in the storyboard.

Comment: Okay, I understand how to change the layout, but how do I bring in the elements that I had in the compact width?

Comment: Open the layout you want, select the item (or items) you want to add to the layout in the left toolbar. Then in the right toolbar select the menu where you can change things like tint color etc. (I forgot the name). At the bottom of this menu you should see something like wC hC Installed or something like this. Then press the + item (not the x) and select the item that says current. This adds the element to the corresponding layout. Now all you have to do is press the Checkmark box.

Comment: Thank you, but this still leaves me having to resize it and make it adapt. Is there a faster way?

Comment: I don't know any faster way to do this.One of the pitfall of autolayout.

Comment: No you have to resize it for the different layouts.

Answer (score 0):

so do like that. after change size class compact regular to any any.
now go to the attribute inspector and as like this image show's .
[image]
installed that object it would start showing on view.